# Interpolation onto a 3d grid from 3 different pairs of points and values

Tags: python, image, numpy, 3d, interpolation

I have three 3D images with me, each representing one of the orthogonal views.  I know the physical `x,y,z` locations on which each of the images are placed.
Let `X1 = {(x1,y1,z1)}` represent the set of physical coordinate tuples for one of the images and for which I know the corresponding intensity values `I1`. There are `N` tuples in `X1` and hence, `N` intensity values. Similarly, I have access to `X2`, `I2`, and `X3`,`I3` which are for the other two images. There are `N` tuples in `X2` and `X3` as well.
I want to estimate the volume that comes from interpolating information from all the views. I know the physical coordinates `Xq` for the final volume as well.
For example:

```
#Let image_matrix1, image_matrix2, and image_matrix3 represent the three #volumes (matrix with intensity values)

#for image/view 1
xs1 = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
ys1 = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
zs1 = np.linspace(-2,2,20)

#for image/view 2
xs2 = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
ys2 = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
zs2 = np.linspace(-2,2,20)

#for image/view 3
xs3 = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
ys3 = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
zs3 = np.linspace(-2,2,20)

#the following will not work, but this is close to what i want to achieve.
xs = [xs1,xs2,xs3]
ys = [ys1,ys2,ys3]
zs = [zs1,zs2,zs3]
points = (xs,ys,zs)
values = [image_matrix1,image_matrix2,image_matrix3]
query = (3.4,2.2,5.2) # the physical point at which i want to know the value
value_at_query = interpolating_function(points,values,query)

#the following will work, but this is for one image only
points = (xs1,ys1,zs1) #modified to take coords of one image only
values = [image_matrix1] #modified to take values of one image only
query = (3.4,2.2,5.2) # the physical point at which i want to know the value
value_at_query = interpolating_function(points,values,query)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to interpolate between the three volumes (as a fourth dimension) as I understand the problem. The volumes are not like a fourth dimension in that they don't lie on a continuous axis that you can interpolate at a specified value.

You could interpolate the views separately and then calculate an aggregate value from the results by a suitable metric (average, quadratic average, min/max, etc.).

```py
value_at_query = suitable_aggregate_metric(
    interpolating_function(points1, [image_matrix1], query),
    interpolating_function(points2, [image_matrix2], query),
    interpolating_function(points3, [image_matrix3], query)
)
```

Considering the extrapolation, you could use a weight-matrix for each image. This weight-matrix would enclose the whole outer cube (128x128x128) with a weight-value of one in the region where it intersects with the image (128x128x10) and decaying to zero towards the outside (probably a strong decay like quadratic/cubic or higher order works better than linear). You then interpolate each image for an intensity-value and a weight-value and then calculate a weighted intensity-average.

The reason for my suggestion is, that if you probe e.g. at location (4, 4, 2.5) you have to extrapolate on every image, but you would want to weight the third image highest, as it is way closer to known values of the image and thus more reliable. A higher order decay exaggerates this weight towards closer values further.

Comment: Maybe my wordings were confusing. 

These three images (image_matrix1, image_matrix2, and image_matrix3) are say the axial (superior-inferior), sagittal(left-right), and the coronal (anterior-posterior) views. Each of the three images is say 128 x 128 x 10. And the 10 slices exist in the middle of the cube (final grid to be populated). From the three 128 x 128 x 10 images, i want to populate the entire cube. So the interpolation at new locations should use information from all the three views. Does this not make sense even now?

Comment: Ah ok, so you have a 128x128x128 cube, and from there you make images from three axis directions, the images containing only a part of that full cube respectively (128x128x10,  128x10x128, 10x128x128). So the images overlap for the inner cube (10x10x10). Now you want to interpolate a value on a given position considering all 3 images. Did I rephrase that correctly?

Comment: Bang on, Sir. Just to be pedantic: interpolate as well as extrapolate. My query points are going to be on the bigger cube as well.

Comment: I added a suggestion about the extrapolation.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the suggestion.
However, i am not sure how to proceed for the original problem. How do i tell the interpolation routine to take { 
{ (xs1,ys1,zs1),image_matrix1}, 
{ (xs2,ys2,zs2),image_matrix2},
{ (xs3,ys3,zs3),image_matrix3}
} 
so that it can give me a value at a query point?
The problem as i mentioned before is that the interpolation methods expect just a single set (tuple) of xs,ys, and zs, in an ascending order. They cannot handle multiple tuples. 
I should look into some pointcloud interpolation i think. Comments?

Comment: Well my suggestion was to only use one set of tuples at a time and basically do three interpolations one for each image seperately. The concrete implementation/syntax/capabilities depend on what interpolation function you are using, or is the search for an interpolation-function part of your question? I'd look into numpy or scipy then.

Comment: Yes, i am looking for the interpolation function which can help me achieve this. The functions interpn and  regulargridinterpolator ask for a single tuple. My problem with using one tuple/image at a time is that it is not using the neighborhood information from the other views.